# How to get URL of current page in PHP

Tags: php, url

In PHP, how can I get the URL of the current page? Preferably just the parts after `http://domain.example`.

Comment: Please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/php-get-the-full-url/8891890#8891890

Comment: Easy way :)
$url = !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off')?"https://":"http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

Answer (score 344, accepted):

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

For more details on what info is available in the $_SERVER array, see [the PHP manual page for it](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

If you also need the query string (the bit after the `?` in a URL), that part is in this variable:

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

Comment: You can also use $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']

Comment: iirc, PHP_SELF and REQUEST_URI will have different values if the page was redirected via mod_rewrite - the former has the path to the actual script, the latter has the originally requested path.

Comment: Err, at least in my apache, 2.2.4, with php 5.3, REQUEST_URI contains the stuff after the ? already...

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is also contaning all query strings, why should I use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` ?

Answer (score 118):

If you want just the parts of URL after `http://domain.example`, try this:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

If the current URL was `http://domain.example/some-slug/some-id`, echo will return only `/some-slug/some-id`.

---

If you want the full URL, try this:

```
<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

Comment: Should you not check if `HTTPS://` is enabled? I found this function to check: `function isSSL() {
    return
   (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off')
   || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443;
  }`

Comment: <?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?> if you just want the domain.

Comment: @ErikThiart, I tried <?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?> and it's displaying like example.com I need like http://www.example.com. Is it possible?

Comment: how about replacing http with REQUEST_SCHEME:
$_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']. "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Answer (score 29):

```
 $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

This will give you the requested directory and file name. If you use mod_rewrite, this is extremely useful because it tells you what page the user was looking at.

If you need the actual file name, you might want to try either `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, the magic constant `__FILE__`, or `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']`. The latter 2 give you the complete path (from the root of the server), rather than just the root of your website. They are useful for includes and such.

`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` gives you the file name relative to the root of the website.

```
 $relative_path = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
 $complete_path = __FILE__;
 $complete_path = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
```

Answer (score 14):

The other answers are correct.  However, a quick note: if you're looking to grab the stuff after the `?` in a URI, you should use the `$_GET[]` array.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` this will give you whole URL for example:

suppose you want to get url of site name `www.example.com` then `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` will give you `https://www.example.com`

Comment: Why does my $_SERVER variable doesn't contain this item??

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` does exactly what it says on the tin, and that is get the URL of the page that sent the user to the page... I.E The referer.

Comment: People who upvoted this answer will have some trouble debugging their code. `HTTP_REFERER` is not the current page, it's the page user was on prior to the current page.

Comment: Also, this isn't always reliable. It is set by the user_agent, not the server -- so, as the PHP manual says (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), "In short, it cannot really be trusted."