# Send URL as a Query String

Tags: php

Think my current page url is:
http://example.com/id=10

In this this page has link to go other page, I want to pass current URL as a query string like this:

http://example.com/about-us/?edit=1&return=http://example.com/id=10

in PHP

```
http://example.com/about-us/?edit=1&return=<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ?>
```

but this is not working, could anyone help me to do this.

Comment: couldn't you just pass the page id, if that's how your url sructure look? I.e. `return=10`

Comment: You need to URI Encode the value of the return parameter...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283327/how-to-get-url-of-current-page-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this (I assume you are using http only);

```
$currentUrl = urlencode("http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");

$link = "http://example.com/about-us/?edit=1&return=" . $currentUrl;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `urlencode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])`

It encodes the link.