# Get Current Url in PHP instead of files root folder url

Tags: php

Hello Friends I want to get the Current Page Url instead of capturing root url of file

I want to capture Like this 
http://localhost/tester/

but coming like this

http://localhost/tester/views/inc/readcountry.php

I have tried like this but it's returning

```
$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
```

localhost/tester/views/inc/readcountry.php

Comment: `DOCUMENT_ROOT` may be the solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get URL of current page in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283327/how-to-get-url-of-current-page-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the full URL in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php)

Comment: @FrayneKonok not working it's returning local directory structure ..

Comment: You mean something like this: `$path = explode("/",$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
echo "http://".$path[0]."/".$path[1];`?

Comment: @Irfan thanx it's working now ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is working perfectly thanx alot

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

Comment: How this is your desire output???? compare _I want to capture Like this http://localhost/SporTwitter/_ and your result.

Comment: @FrayneKonok I want to capture like this localhost/SporTwitter instead of capturing files root url.

Answer (score 1):

A little handy function I found somewhere else might help you out.

```
function url() {
  return sprintf(
    "%s://%s%s",
    isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' ? 'https' : 'http',
    $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
  );
}
```

To use it:

```
echo url();
```

Comment: Thanx Peter I got the solution, this one i have tried $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']    I Will also check your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

if you want the full url, try this:

```
<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

> $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] - header from the current request, if there is one.
>
> $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] - the URI which was given in order to access this page; for instance, '/index.html'.
>
> $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] - it is your parameters and values in URL

---

My htaccess for MVC app:

> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteRule !.(js|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php

Plus in each directory (model, views, controllers) i putted htaccess too:

> Deny from all

Comment: Thanx for Your reply, This one I have tried but returning like this  http://localhost/SporTwitter/views/inc/readcountry.php but my requirement is like this   http://localhost/SporTwitter

Comment: @Rahul In my MVC framework i used mod_rewrite in apache. It helped me.

Comment: Thanx I will keep your Suggestion in my Note.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing which is the point of the tree you need to stop the capture, I may suggest you to have a look at all the content of the [$_SERVER] array, dumping it, and at the php magic constants.

Comment: Thanx for Your suggestion i am going to check now