# How can I get the first part of URL til arguments?

Tags: php, url, path, directory

I use Xampp. Here is my directory:

```
\xampp
    \htdocs
        \myweb
            index.php 
            \classes
                 autoloader.php
                 classname.php
```

And here is the URL:

```
http://localhost/myweb/classname/methodname/idNum?arg=val
```

And I want to get this part: *(everything until `index.php` layer)*

```
http://localhost/myweb
```

How can I do that?

**Note1:** `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` doesn't return expected thing. It just returns `localhost`.

**Note2:** I can get the whole of URL and then parse it by regex to grab expected result .. But I don't want to do that because sometimes `myweb` folder goes away.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get URL of current page in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283327/how-to-get-url-of-current-page-in-php)

Comment: @Winter Did you even read the question?

Comment: It's all about getting the url and removing a part. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] will return the full url and you just have to cut it.

Comment: $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); and then explode it and use what u need

Comment: When processing that URL, how is it supposed to know where the `index.php` layer is?

Comment: @Barmar There is this variable `$_GET['rt']` in the *index.php* which contains the rest of URL *(in this case `classname/methodname/idNum?arg=val`)*. I need to get everything which is before the value of that variable.

Comment: Use `str_replace()` to remove that from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Comment: Or use `strpos()` to find the position, and `substr()` to return everything before that position.

Comment: These are basic string operations, nothing to do with a URL at all.

Comment: @Barmar You know, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` doesn't contain `http://localhost` *(I mean hostname)*

Comment: use whatever variable contains the original URL that you want to extract the prefix from.

Comment: @stack how about `'http://' + $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] + $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] - $_GET['rt']` ?