# Get URL by $_GET

Tags: php, get

I need get current url (url can be different), I want send this url to email by ajax form, but I cant get right url. I use:

```
echo $_GET['ref']
```

But it return empty value.

**Addition:**
I have ajax form which send some data (including current url) to my email.
Yes, I use this 2 values:

```
$url1 = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$url2 = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

But it return me url like this:

```
/cloud/abuse/abuse_mailer.php
```

not my current URL.

Comment: It may help $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. Ref : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283327/how-to-get-url-of-current-page-in-php

Comment: $_GET only shows parameters transferred by get, I.E.: everything after the question mark. try your luck in `var_dump($_SERVER)`

Comment: Please provide some more information on what you would like to achieve (e.g. show some more of your code)!

Comment: Added some additions in post. ['REQUEST_URI'] give me incorrect url, not current.

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET` is an array containing data passed through a **GET request method**. If you want to get your current URL, then you can use `$_SERVER`; it contains server and request data. As an example:

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // outputs current URI of client
```

Or you can try:

```
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

Comment: It gives me url wich generating after sending form /cloud/abuse/abuse_mailer.php, but I need original url from which I send my form.

Comment: Thanks, but as result the same url ...abuse/abuse_mailer.php