# How do I get $_SERVER[] and variable value echo-ed?

Tags: php, url

I have this URL lets say:

```
www.abc.com/item?id=10
```

When ever I do this:

```
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
```

I get only:

```
www.abc.com
```

How do I get the whole URL with appended variable?

Comment: `print_r($_SERVER);` will show you all the variables you have to work with

Comment: i think what you are looking for is the $_GET variable and not $_SERVER but i dont understand your question correctly maybe

Comment: Whoever wrote base($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])... worked

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php

Answer (score 0):

use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` as follows

```
echo "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
/* Or */
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']."://". $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to take the full URL with: (for example)

```
<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

Good topics:

- [Get the full URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php)
- [How to get URL of current page in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283327/how-to-get-url-of-current-page-in-php)